# Illustrator CC 2014 - SVG coordinates keep shifting position

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, sprite

I'm using Illustrator CC 2014 to create a sprite sheet for use on the web. The artboard and icons are 16px wide. My problem is, the positions of the icons seem to shift, and I can't figure out why. The icons should have an X position of 0px but they keep changing back to -0.0007px after I edit the X position. Sometimes the icons themselves change size too; I could click on one and it would be something like 16.03432px wide. Why is this happening?

I thought it might be the reference point, but i have the art board and all elements set to top left and X: 0px.

The problem for me is when I export as an SVG, the image is sometimes a pixel off which messes up my sprite display on the front end.

I have a link to the ai file in question: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1950611/header-icons.ai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your size is not exactly 16px. After I changed it to 16 (click once changed 16.00003 to 16, but it does not actually work; you will have to reduce to 15 or 14 and then go back to 16) for the first icon and align horizontally to the artboard and it seems fine for me now.

You can take a look at [it](https://app.box.com/s/42k3h2a38whjbnj5vqlb8ou7tviazqva) yourself.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! Just to clarify, what exactly wasn't 16px? The art board?

Comment: @PaulColinRedmond The first icon.

Comment: Is this a bug in illustrator?

Comment: @PaulColinRedmond It is probably your own problem, not a bug I believe.